# How to get the updated value and apply it to another function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

as for someone new to react native, how can I get the updated value from usestate and apply it to another function? for example here is my code:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.scanButton}
                title="Scan"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("BarcodeScanner")}
            >
                <Text style={styles.scanText}>Scan</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Barcode Value ... "
                // i want to put the updated value here in "value"
                value=""
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

```
function BarcodeScanner() {
    const [barcodeData, setBarcodeData] = useState();

    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
        setScanned(true);
        Alert.alert("Result", `Barcode data ${data} has been scanned!`, [
            {
                text: "Cancle",
                onPress: () => console.log("Cancle pressed"),
            },
            {
                text: "Apply",
              onPress: () => setBarcodeData(data),
            },
        ]);
        
    };
```

I have tried for hours but I didn't come to a solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could pass the `barcodeData` back to the `HomeScreen` using `route params`. Actually, from the code that you have provided, we could remove the state in `BarcodeScanner` and pass `data` in the `handleBarCodeScanned` function directly.

This could be implemented as follows. I assume that `HomeScreen` is a `Screen` defined in a navigator.

```js
function BarcodeScanner() {
       const navigation = useNavigation()

        Alert.alert("Result", `Barcode data ${data} has been scanned!`, [
            {
                text: "Cancle",
                onPress: () => console.log("Cancle pressed"),
            },
            {
                text: "Apply",
              onPress: () => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", {data: data}),
            },
        ]);
        
};
```

In `Homescreen`, we handle the state.

```js
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
    const [barcodeData, setBarcodeData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
         if (route.params) {
             setBarcodeData(route.params.data)
         }
    }, [route.params])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.scanButton}
                title="Scan"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("BarcodeScanner")}
            >
                <Text style={styles.scanText}>Scan</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Barcode Value ... "
                value={barcodeData}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```